# Column naming in Postgresql functions

Tags: database, function, postgresql

I want to create a PSQL function which returns a table like result. My function definition looks like below:

```
create or replace function myfunc1() 
   returns table(id varchar(50), title varchar(50)) 
as $$ 
begin 
   return query select id, title from books; 
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;
```

But, when I call the function, I got this error:

> ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
>   LINE 1: select id, title from books
>                  ^
>   DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.

Apparently, it is because I use the column name 'id' in both the return table and my target table. The simplest solution would be changing the column names. But I am here to look for a way that would let me use the column name I want. Besides, changing the name would make my code weird, and difficult for other to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the ambiguity by qualifying column names:

```
create or replace function myfunc1()
  returns table(id varchar(50), title varchar(50)) as
$$
  select books.id, books.title from books;
$$ language sql stable;
```

Comment: Actually when switching from plpgsql to sql, it's not necessary to qualify the columns because sql does not have named parameters as plpgsql does and therefor no "name clash" happens.

Comment: True, but see the recent discussions on the pg-hackers list: Pavel, if memory serves, suggested a patch that introduce them (and a few other core devs were quite hostile to the idea). :-D

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT books.id, title FROM books`?

Answer (score 0):

That `... returns table(id varchar(50), title varchar(50)) ...` part of the function definition is just [another way to define OUT parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html). So now you have two OUT parameters named `id` and `title` and two columns (from the `book` table) you refer to named... yes, you guessed it - `id` and `title`.

A way to avoid this ambiguity is to rename the column names of the returned table in your function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc1() RETURNS TABLE(p_id VARCHAR(50), p_title VARCHAR(50)) AS $_$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT id, title FROM books;
END;
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```